# Issues with MinHeaps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm trying to develop custom path-finding for the game I'm making. It's using the new 2D colliders so I can't use unity's built in navmesh. So instead of using an asset someone else created I figured I'd have a go at making my own implementation.

I've looked up a bunch of stuff about path-finding and A*, which I have no problem at all understanding. Where I'm having troubles though is the MinHeap. I've never looked into bit shifting and the like so I modified some code I found in a tutorial to suit my needs.

The problem that I'm having is that, from what I can tell in my debugging, it isn't properly sorting the nodes by cost value. From what I can see, and I'll post a picture below so you know what I'm talking about, every node that's being added to the open list is staying where it's added, so it's more like a Dijkstra's search then an A* one.

Could someone look at the code and tell me if I'm doing something very wrong.. because this is driving me mad.

This is the code:

```
using System;

public class NodeList<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{        
    private int count;
    private int capacity;
    private T temp;
    private T mheap;
    private T[] array;
    private T[] tempArray;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.count; }
    }

    public NodeList() : this(16) { }

    public NodeList(int capacity)
    {
        this.count = 0;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        array = new T[capacity];
    }

    public void BuildHead()
    {
        int position;
        for (position = (this.count - 1) >> 1; position >= 0; position--)
        {
            this.MinHeapify(position);
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {            
        this.count++;
        if (this.count > this.capacity)
        {
            DoubleArray();
        }
        this.array[this.count - 1] = item;
        int position = this.count - 1;

        int parentPosition = ((position - 1) >> 1);

        while (position > 0 && array[parentPosition].CompareTo(array[position]) > 0)    
        {
            temp = this.array[position];
            this.array[position] = this.array[parentPosition];
            this.array[parentPosition] = temp;
            position = parentPosition;
            parentPosition = ((position - 1) >> 1);
        }
    }            

    private void DoubleArray()
    {
        this.capacity <<= 1;
        tempArray = new T[this.capacity];
        CopyArray(this.array, tempArray);
        this.array = tempArray;
    }

    private static void CopyArray(T[] source, T[] destination)
    {
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < source.Length; index++)
        {
            destination[index] = source[index];
        }
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this.count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Heap is empty");
        }
        return this.array[0];
    }


    public T ExtractFirst()
    {
        if (this.count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Heap is empty");
        }
        temp = this.array[0];            
        this.array[0] = this.array[this.count - 1];
        this.count--;
        this.MinHeapify(0);
        return temp;
    }

    private void MinHeapify(int position)
    {
        do
        {
            int left = ((position << 1) + 1);
            int right = left + 1;
            int minPosition;

            if (left < count && array[left].CompareTo(array[position]) < 0)
            {
                minPosition = left;
            }
            else
            {
                minPosition = position;
            }

            if (right < count && array[right].CompareTo(array[minPosition]) < 0)    
            {
                minPosition = right;
            }

            if (minPosition != position)
            {
                mheap = this.array[position];
                this.array[position] = this.array[minPosition];
                this.array[minPosition] = mheap;
                position = minPosition;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

        } while (true);
    }
}
```

My path searches from the end point to the start (From where the player clicks, to the player), so the "Starting point" is the grey node in the middle of the screen:
[Pathfinding issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJJrx.jpg)

This is why it's a problem:
[Issue 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ii64.jpg)

Comment: There are a whole bunch of C# binary heap implementations in Internet. Why not use one of them?

Comment: And why is this called `NodeList`?

Comment: @SergeyKrusch Its called 'NodeList' just so it's an easier name to read in the code. Makes more sense to me when I see it then 'MinHeap'. And this is one that I pulled off the internet. I should go ahead and state that I have solved the issue I was having, and it was nothing to do with the heap. Turns out I was assigning my costs wrong to the nodes.